# Problems when deleting resource files C#

Tags: c#, toolstrip, menustrip, statusstrip

When I delete resource files from my C# project all the menustrip, toolstrip and status strips items are removed from their respective strips.

These lines of code are deleted everytime it happens.

```
        this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem,
        this.processToolStripMenuItem,
        this.toolStripMenuItem1,
        this.windowsToolStripMenuItem,
        this.adminToolStripMenuItem,
        this.helpToolStripMenuItem1});
```

Is there:

a) a way to stop this?

b) a reason why it does this?

Comment: I've had problems with menu strips etc in forms projects before, was never able to pin down the cause; one question though - why are you deleting the resource files?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan I'm designing background images, I'm editing them then checking what they look like then changing them and when i import the new one it leaves the old resource there and I don't want a backlog of unused resource files. Forgive me if there is a way of overwriting them I'm new to C#. We were taught java at University so working with C# for the first time.